# svn status location mean

Tags: svn, external

I used "svn st" to an svn root which has external file and directory.
Every times file and directory 's status "X" has diff location.is it a rule?,I can't find in doc.

[image: screenshot]

Comment: Please add your code so we can help you. Thanks!

Comment: Just use "svn st"

Comment: What do you mean by "Every times file and directory 's status "X" has diff location"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`svn status` output is formatted in columns.
When you use `svn help status` you can have a look what these columns are and what the contents mean.
For your `X` it is:

> First column: Says if item was added, deleted, or otherwise changed
> 'X' an unversioned directory created by an externals definition
>
> Fifth column: Whether the item is switched or a file external
> 'X' a versioned file created by an eXternals definition

Be aware, that the [documentation on svn status](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.8/svn.ref.svn.c.status.html) for some reason does not contain the information about the fifth column.